# How to access list item when built with builder?

Tags: flutter

In the following Flutter app, I'm trying to show a LinearProgressIndicator in each card only when that card is counting.  The the correct progression is printed to the console, but I can't figure out how to access "stepProgress" variable from the LinearProgressIndicator widget to update the view.

The cards are being built with a builder because they will change based on the input List (Array) of Maps (Objects).

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final key = new GlobalKey<_MyHomePageState>();
List<Widget> cards = [];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App Title',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        canvasColor: Colors.grey[350],
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Title', key: key),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List _sequence = [];
  double stepProgress = 0.0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() => _sequence = [
          {'iterations': 1, 'time': 10},
          {'iterations': 3, 'time': 7},
          {'iterations': 2, 'time': 5},
        ]);

    setState(() {
      cards = getRun();
    });

    _countdown(_sequence, null);
  }

  getRun() {
    List<Widget> runCards = [];
    for (var group in _sequence) {
      runCards.add(_buildCard(CardModel(
        iterationsInGroup: group['iterations'],
        timeEach: group['time'],
      )));
    }
    return runCards;
  }

  void _countdown(seq, iters) async {
    if (seq.length > 0) {
      int i = iters == null ? seq[0]['iterations'] : iters;
      if (i > 0) {
        int duration = seq[0]["time"];
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
          if (timer.tick < duration) {
            setState(() {
              stepProgress = timer.tick / duration;
            });
            print('Iteration $i:  ${timer.tick} / $duration = $stepProgress');
          } else {
            print('Finished iteration $i');
            timer.cancel();
            i = i - 1;
            if (i > 0) {
              _countdown(seq, i); // Next iteration
            } else {
              print('Finished group ${seq.length}');
              timer.cancel();
              if (seq.length > 1) {
                _countdown(seq.sublist(1), null); // Next group
              } else {
                print('Done');
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Text(
              'Header',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: cards,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildCard(CardModel card) {
  List<Widget> columnData = <Widget>[];

  columnData.add(
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            card.timeEach.toString() +
                ' seconds ' +
                card.iterationsInGroup.toString() +
                ' times',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
          ),
        ),
        true //key.currentState.activeStep == card.cardStep //TODO: This doesn't work
            ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                value: key.currentState.stepProgress,
              )
            : Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0),
      ],
    ),
  );

  return Card(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
      child: Column(children: columnData),
    ),
  );
}

class CardModel {
  final int iterationsInGroup;
  final int timeEach;

  CardModel({
    this.iterationsInGroup,
    this.timeEach,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code a little, this is a little messy therefore I recommend you the following:

- Create a `StatefulWidget` for your ChildView (Like my code below).
- Keep the progress logic into the ChildView, it would be easy to change the status in that way.
- I had to keep track the `Globalkey` in order to refresh the changes into the child view, but if you handle the logic into each child, you don't need the `GlobalKey`.

  ```
      import 'dart:async';

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

  final key = new GlobalKey<_MyHomePageState>();

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App Title',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          canvasColor: Colors.grey[350],
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Title', key: key),
      );
    }
  }

  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

    final String title;

    @override
    State createState() => _MyHomePageState();
  }

  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    List _sequence = [];
   List<ChildView> runCards = [];
    @override
    initState() {
      super.initState();
      setState(() => _sequence = [
            {'iterations': 1, 'time': 10, 'progress': 0.0},
            {'iterations': 3, 'time': 7, 'progress': 0.0},
            {'iterations': 2, 'time': 5, 'progress': 0.0},
          ]);
      getRun();
      _countdown(_sequence, null);
    }

    getRun() {
      for (var group in _sequence) {
        var cardModel = CardModel(
          iterationsInGroup: group['iterations'],
          timeEach: group['time'],
          progress: group['progress'],
        );

        runCards.add(new ChildView(cardModel,new GlobalKey<_ChildViewState>()));
      }
      setState(() {

          });
      return runCards;
    }

    void _countdown(seq, iters) async {
      if (seq.length > 0) {
        int i = iters == null ? seq[0]['iterations'] : iters;
        if (i > 0) {
          int duration = seq[0]["time"];
          Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
            if (timer.tick <= duration) {
              var childView = runCards[i-1];
              double stepProgress = 0.0;
              stepProgress = timer.tick / duration;
              childView.key.currentState.updateProgress(stepProgress);

              print('Iteration $i:  ${timer.tick} / $duration = $stepProgress');
            } else {
              print('Finished iteration $i');
              timer.cancel();
              i = i - 1;
              if (i > 0) {
                _countdown(seq, i); // Next iteration
              } else {
                print('Finished group ${seq.length}');
                timer.cancel();
                if (seq.length > 1) {
                  _countdown(seq.sublist(1), null); // Next group
                } else {
                  print('Done');
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Text(
                'Header',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: runCards,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  class CardModel {
    final int iterationsInGroup;
    final int timeEach;
    double progress;

    CardModel({
      this.iterationsInGroup,
      this.timeEach,
      this.progress,
    });
  }


  class ChildView extends StatefulWidget {

   final CardModel card;
   final GlobalKey<_ChildViewState> key;
   ChildView(this.card, this.key) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _ChildViewState createState() => _ChildViewState();
  }

  class _ChildViewState extends State<ChildView> {

    void updateProgress(double progress){
       setState(() {
              widget.card.progress = progress;
            });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      List<Widget> columnData = <Widget>[];

    columnData.add(
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              widget.card.timeEach.toString() +
                  ' seconds ' +
                  widget.card.iterationsInGroup.toString() +
                  ' times',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
            ),
          ),
          widget.card.progress < 1 //key.currentState.activeStep == card.cardStep //TODO: This doesn't work
              ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: widget.card.progress,
                )
              : Container( child: new Text("Completed"),),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
        child: Column(children: columnData),
      ),
    );
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  With this code, the wrong progress bars are updating.  The first should run through one time, the second should run through 3 times, and the third should run through 2 times.  It seems to jump around between them.

Comment: You should change the logic, I was helping you in how to comunicate the state of your child views.

Comment: The logic prints to the console correctly, but the progress bars on the cards are jumbled.  Watching the "key" value, they are all set to the same value of "LabeledGlobalKey".  Shouldn't the key's have different values?

Comment: try to put the logic in the child view , each child could track their own progress

Comment: The problem was just with setting which card to update.  After changing this it works properly:
            var childView = runCards[_sequence.length - seq.length];

Comment: nice !! :)  glad to help you